# Drop-down picklist field is mandatory in a flow screen

Tags: visual-workflow, salesforcedx

In flow design, picklists are by default mandatory, Is there any solution to make a dropdown optional ? 
I had a look in salesforce help and I found this [article here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000269556&language=en_US&type=1)

Comment: The article that you have referenced states -- *This behavior is working as designed and there is no option to make drop-downs optional.* But it also mentions a workaround which is what is the option here.

Comment: yes but the workaround mentioned is not the  best solution if I have 100 records .